# I can't implement a function that shifts elements in an array

Tags: c

I can't shift elements positions in an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mv(int n1, int n2);

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 0, 1 };
    mv(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
    printf("%i,%i", numbers[0], numbers[1]);
}

void mv(int n1, int n2)
{
    int temp = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = temp;
}
```

The code shifts the elements inside the function but not the array position

Comment: Indentation would make your code easier to read...

Comment: You're swapping the arguments passed to your function, not the elements of the array. Remember C uses pass by value.

Comment: If you want the function to modify the array elements, pass pointers and then indirect through them.

Comment: The function parameters are passed by value so they are copies of the originals. To swap the original values you would need to use pointers or pass the array along with the indices to swap.

Comment: `void swap (int arr[], size_t i1, size_t i2) {int temp = arr[i1]; arr[i1] = arr[i2]; arr[i2] = tmp; }` and call like `swap(numbers, 0, 1);`

Comment: Solution is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8oK383jKr).  Passing pointers/addresses of integers to a function will allow that function to update variables, and remain updated on return of that function.  Cheers...

Answer (score 2):

To shift the array you need to move all (-1) of its elements.

```
int *shiftL(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    if(arr && size)
    {
        for(size_t index = 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            arr[index - 1] = arr[index];
        }
        arr[size - 1] = 0;
    }
    return arr;
}

int *shiftR(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    if(arr && size)
    {
        for(size_t index = size - 1; index ; index--)
        {
            arr[index] = arr[index - 1];
        }
        arr[0] = 0;
    }
    return arr;
}

int *shiftLmemmove(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    if(arr && size)
    {
        if(size > 1) memmove(arr, arr + 1, (size - 1) *sizeof(*arr));
        arr[size - 1] = 0;
    }
    return arr;
}

int *shiftRmemmove(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    if(arr && size)
    {
        if(size > 1) memmove(arr + size - 1, arr + size - 2, (size - 1) *sizeof(*arr));
        arr[0] = 0;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

we have 2 types of function in respect to parameters , 1 - Parameters passed by value , 2 - parameters passed by reference (pointer - Array)
the main difference between them is that when you pass by value the function takes copies of the parameters and perform the code on these copies and when it finished .. the Stack frame(which contains these copied parameters) gets destroyed so everything you have done on these parameters is changed and destroyed so the passed variables didn't get effected . the second type (call by reference) you are using the addresses of the variables which means that you actually are using these variables not any copies ofthem.

```
    void mv(int *n1, int *n2)
    {
        int temp = *n1;
        n1 = *n2;
        *n2 = temp;
    }
```

when you are dealing with arrays this way is how you perform operations on it because even if you want to pass it by value it will be so bad for memory and may cause Overflow especially when you want to perform another branched functions.

Answer (score 1):

It isnt working because variables in a function create copies in stack and you are swapping their values. You should be passing the values by reference and your program should also accept variable's address.

```
void mv (int *n1, int *n2){
int temp = *n1;
*n1 = *n2;
*n2 = temp;}
```

In main function:

```
mv(&numbers[0], &numbers[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the good comments, what is happening within your function stays within your function because of the "pass by value" characteristics of your function signature.  What you most likely want is to pass a reference to your array to the function (a pointer reference) and then perform the necessary tasks (in this case, swapping the two values).

I was working on a refactored version of your code while the good comments were being entered, but this should be a representative illustration of what you would want to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mv (int *arry);    /* Passing a pointer reference */

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {0,1};
    printf("Before: %i,%i\n",numbers[0],numbers[1]);
    mv(numbers);
    printf("After.: %i,%i\n",numbers[0],numbers[1]);
}

void mv (int *arry)
{
    int temp = arry[1];
    arry[1]  = arry[0];
    arry[0]  = temp;
}
```

Following is the test output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Movement/bin/Release$ ./Movement 
Before: 0,1
After.: 1,0
```

The main take-away is probably do some more reading of "C" tutorials especially focusing in on parameter usage within functions.

Comment: The question is confusing because the OP uses *shift* in place of *swap*